# create an id for each image being displayed on the slider (Basic jQuery Slider)

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Need to create a dynamic label with the "title" of each image, however this label is not within the slide. I'm using the plugin: Basic jQuery Slider 
the way to do this would label:

```
<p><script>document.getElementById("ID of the current image being displayed");</script></p>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I may be missing something here, but this question isn't clear to me.  Can you add in the code you have written so we can trouble-shoot it?

Comment: hello Maria I'm afraid that your question needs to be more specific. What do you want to achieve? Where exactly are you stuck? Plus a litle bit of more code would be much apriciated. Do you know that you can use jQuery's inbuild selector? the $('#youridhere') or $('.yourclasshere') or $('p') etc. So you would not need to use the normal javascript getElementById!

Comment: the event ID would be created only when the image was visible
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should fit your requirements. For demonstration see this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GpR5t/).

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    function displayTitle() {
        var imageTitle = $('img:visible').attr('title'); // get the title from the visible image
        $('#title').html('Title: ' + imageTitle);
    }

    $('input:radio').bind('click', function () {
        var selectedIndex = $(this).val();

        $('img').hide(); // hide all images
        $('img').eq(selectedIndex).show(); // show image selected by radiobutton

        displayTitle();
    });

    displayTitle();
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="title"></div>

<input type="radio" name="display-image" value="0">display image-1
<input type="radio" name="display-image" value="1">display image-2
<input type="radio" name="display-image" value="2">display image-3

<br />

<img title="image-1" alt="image-1"  />
<img title="image-2" alt="image-2" style="display:none" />
<img title="image-3" alt="image-3" style="display:none" />
```